# Garbage memory?

Tags: c++, pointers, garbage-collection

I was just going through an article which explains about Wild pointers. For garbage memory, it states that when a pointer pointing to a memory object is lost, i.e. it indicates that the memory item continues to exits, but the pointer to it is lost; it happens when memory is not released explicitly. I was trying to understand this with an example. Here is what I wrote

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int q =12;
int point()
{
   int *p;
   p = &q;
   //delete p;
}
int main()
{
   point();
   return 0;
}
```

So, in the above example, memory item (q) continues to exist, but the pointer to it is lost. I may have misunderstood it all wrong, but if I understood it correctly, then does this example addresses 'garbage memory' definition given above? If yes, then I should use delete p, right?

Comment: Only `delete` what you `new`. Better yet, employ RAII so you don't have to `delete` anything.

Comment: yes, I shouldnt have delete that. RAII?

Comment: Smart pointers instead of dynamically allocated raw ones, vectors instead of dynamic arrays, your own RAII class for a specific resource. The point is that you don't have to clean up and it's better than a garbage collector.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++ Does not have garbage collection the way you understand it.. But what you are showing is **not a "memory leak"** which is what I think you mean.

In this case you are pointing to a memory location that is **NOT dynamically allocated**, and is accessible from outside the function for the duration of the program.

---

```
int point()
{
   int *p = new int();
   //delete p;
}
```

This is now a **memory leak**, since the memory is still allocated, but noone can access it any more. If this were Java or any other language which supports GC, this **memory would now be queued to be Garbage collected**.

---

The ***recommended style in C++*** is to **make all allocated memory auto deallocate themselves**, as far as possible, with a concept called **[Resource Acquisition Is Initialization (RAII)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)**, using **smart pointers** as below.

```
int point()
{
   std::unique_ptr<int> p(new int());
   //delete p;  // not needed.
}
```

When the variable p is destroyed, at the end of its scope, it will automatically call `delete` on the allocated memory so you dont have to. By making stuff clean up after themselves, we enable the below.

> C++ is my favorite garbage collected language because it generates so
>   little garbage
>
> > Bjarne Stroustrup's FAQ: Did you really say that?.
> >     Retrieved on 2007-11-15.
> >     http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup

Comment: Can you give an example/ or a hint to the one, which addresses the 'garbage collection' definition above?